# How can I extend Mac + keyboard + mouse to a PC through WiFi local network?

Tags: macos, mac, network, wifi, windows

I have a windows laptop and a Mac that connect together to WiFi and that is connected to the Internet. I don't have wired (ethernet) network in home and i just have Wife at home.

My goal is to extend my Mac keyboard / mouse display so that the windows is a second screen and not simply mirroring what's on the Main Mac.

[image]

I researched this software, but I can't get it to work:

> Synergy is a software download that shares one mouse and one keyboard between multiple computers. Simply move your mouse between your computers effortlessly. You can even copy and paste between computers. Synergy works on Windows, macOS, Linux, and Raspberry Pi. You only need a regular Ethernet or WiFi network connection, and no special hardware. It works like magic.

Other research like  Mouseshare, Synergy , symless.com all of these softwares just need to a network and I don't think they work with wireless.

I don't get why my WiFi isn't working with this solution and I think it needs to "cable network" that i don't have. Can someone confirm this setup works or how I would know why my WiFi isn't working for this case?

Comment: Please continue to edit if I made mistakes or you have a specific error message or are just worried the setup won't work based on what you're reading. Thanks for the clarifying edits!

Comment: There is no error. just i cant connect to device through Wifie as easily and they are trying to show

Answer (score 1):

If I were trying to do what I **think** you're trying to do I would use [Microsoft's Remote Desktop.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17463/windows-7-connect-to-another-computer-remote-desktop-connection) It's [available for macos from the App Store via this link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-remote-desktop-10/id1295203466). It's also free (as in zero cost), so you've only a bit of time to lose for trying it.

I've used it for years, and found it works quite well for my purposes. I've tried other methods, but for connecting to a Windows host, they always feel "clunky" in comparison.

Comment: i want to see 2 different things in 2 different displays with the same mouse and keyboard.

Comment: i found the solution by this video :  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ldIdz6LFUA   http://business-plan.ir

Comment: Why didn't I think of that?